# There's a specific website like jsFiddle, but i can't remember the name/url. Can you help?

Tags: webapp-rec

A while ago i found a website much like jsFiddle, focused on collaborative editing. It has forking and it's full of HTML5 experiments. Unfortunately i can't remember the name; do you by any chance know which website it is?

EDIT
It's not jsbin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Flash, there are these two sites, both related:

- http://wonderfl.net/
- http://beautifl.net/

More canvas-related is Aza Raskin's http://azarask.in/projects/algorithm-ink

More JS-related: http://jsdo.it/

Comment: The website i'm looking for is very much like those, but for javascript/html5/css.  Close call though. :)

Comment: Edited answer :)

Comment: Now jsfiddle also has collaboration feature to share fiddle in real time :)